# How shard a collection with data inside sharded cluster MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, partitioning, sharding

I want to shard a collection with data. When I try with **sh.shardCollection("myDb.myCollection", {id:"hashed"})** then this collection shard but it's not spread to the whole shards. only spread to the primary shard. for example,

Empty collection after shard,

[sh.status() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POMWi.png)

Then data add it will spread to whole shards

Collection with data after shard,

[sh.status() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTVRO.png)

When data add only goes to the primary shard.

My question is how correctly shard a collection with data in MongoDB. Have any other alternative way?

Comment: How much data did you insert into the collection? Sharding is done by chunks, the default chuck size is 64 MB (in MongoDB version 6.0 even 128 MB). You need to insert some data before sharding takes effect. See [Data Partitioning with Chunks](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/)

Comment: yes, you are correct. I test with only a small amount of data. that is the case. after I set the chunk size to 2 MB and tried with 10000 data it split into multiple chunks and spread to whole shards. now it's working fine thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Wernfried Domscheit in the comments about the fact that the cluster will take care of distributing the data once the collection is sharded. As mentioned, that is done based on writing to the collection and happens over time. Your test may have too little data or too few writes to trigger the changes.

To your specific question about the initial distribution of chunks, this is covered in the documentation. Applying a hashed shard key on an empty collection in your first example is covered [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/hashed-sharding/#shard-an-empty-collection):

> The sharding operation creates empty chunks to cover the entire range of the shard key values and performs an initial chunk distribution. By default, the operation creates 2 chunks per shard and migrates across the cluster. You can use `numInitialChunks` option to specify a different number of initial chunks. This initial creation and distribution of chunks allows for faster setup of sharding.

And behavior on the collection with data is covered just above it [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/hashed-sharding/#shard-a-populated-collection):

> The sharding operation creates the initial chunk(s) to cover the entire range of the shard key values. The number of chunks created depends on the configured chunk size.

Both of these described behaviors match what you have demonstrated in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Ya, I got the point you mentioned here. All are clear now. Thank you for your time!